# How to resolve issue in installing Apache Cassandra?

Tags: installation, cassandra

I am new to Apache Cassandra. I am trying to install on my windows its giving be the error path cannot be found. Can someone help resolve this issue

Here is the error

```
C:\Users\kanir\apache-cassandra-3.11.14\bin>cassandra
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra cannot be installed on windows by default. Often the better advice is to run it with Docker. Now with WSL2 and powershell it can now be executed

[This documentation](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-windows) explains step-by-step the elements needed in the Path and third-party components like Java 8 or python 3.6